# Does the powershell cmdlet 'Stop-Service' prevent the rest of the script from executing until the service has stopped?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am writing a script to shut down a list of services using the Stop-Service cmdlet.

My question is: does the Stop-Service cmdlet wait until the service has stopped before continuing with the rest of the script? Or does the script immediately continue after executing the Stop-Service command regardless of outcome?

Script below

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Services = 'service1','service2','service3';

#Stop Services
foreach ($svcName in $Services) {
    $serviceObj = Get-Service -name $svcName
    if($serviceObj.Status -eq 'Running') {
        Stop-Service $serviceObj
    }
}
```

For example: if all services take 10 seconds to stop each, will this script take 10 seconds to run or 30? (Assuming successful shut down)

I am trying to determine how long this script will take on average.

Comment: Did you try it? You can set a timer to quantify/qualify execution time. No need to guess.

Comment: In short: Yes, `Stop-Service` is synchronous, but there's a fixed 2-second timeout. If you want it to be asynchronous, pass `-NoWait`.  See the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment.

```
($Stopwatch = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew())

(
    Get-Service | 
    Select-Object -Property Name, Status
) -match 'Running' | 
Select-Object -First 3 | 
Stop-Service

$Stopwatch.Elapsed
# Resuults
<#
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 6
Milliseconds      : 182
Ticks             : 61827905
TotalDays         : 7.15600752314815E-05
TotalHours        : 0.00171744180555556
TotalMinutes      : 0.103046508333333
TotalSeconds      : 6.1827905
TotalMilliseconds : 6182.7905
#>
```